# Using @PreAuthorize in a method that returns a SseEmitter returns HTTP 406

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using jwt for authentication, I'm suspecting that it has something to do with the request header which has the token.

Receiving a server sent event without adding @PreAuthorize works just fine:

```
@GetMapping("/sse")
public SseEmitter serverSentEvent() throws IOException
{
   SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(2592000000L);
   emitter.send("OK");

   return emitter;
}
```

How ever when i add @PreAuthorize to check use role, i get a 406 response (can’t establish a connection to the server at http://localhost:8080/sse)

```
@GetMapping("/sse")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
public SseEmitter serverSentEvent() throws IOException
{
   SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(2592000000L);
   emitter.send("OK");

   return emitter;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an `Accept` header of any kind in your request?

Comment: I didn't set any Accept header, just the Authorization header with the token.

Comment: HTTP 406 is "Not Acceptable", so the hint may be that you require an accept header.  It may also be the case that your endpoint needs to accept some MIME-type as well (like `application/json` or something more appropriate).

Comment: I'm using EventSource on the client, which sends a GET request to the URL with the accept header `text/event-stream`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the JWT interceptor wasn't adding the token in authorization header for EventSource requests, so I used [ng-event-source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-event-source) which allows for custom HTTP headers in EventSource.